# How to get all customer's biggest order in neo4j's northwind graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j's cypher noob here.

Using the demo Northwind graph,
i'd like to retrieve all customers with their biggest order (order with the most products)

Sorry if it's a silly question, but i can't figure out the query.

My attempt:

```
MATCH (c :Customer)-->(o :Order)-->(p :Product) 
WITH c,o, count(p) as cp ORDER BY cp DESC LIMIT 1 
RETURN c,o
```

but return only one customer with his biggest order,but i need the list of all customers with their respective biggest order.

Comment: Show us how far along your attempts.

Comment: MATCH (c :Customer)-->(o :Order)-->(p :Product)
WITH c,o, count(p) as cp
ORDER BY cp DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN c,o

this one return only one customer with his biggest order,
i need the same but for all customers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the limit applies to the entire previous result. You need to [collect](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/aggregation/#aggregation-collect) orders and `cp` for each customer, and get first. For example:

```
MATCH (c :Customer)-->(o :Order)-->(p :Product) 
WITH c, o, count(p) as cp ORDER BY cp DESC
WITH c, collect({order: o, count: cp}) as orders
RETURN c.companyName, 
       orders[0]['order'] as o,
       orders[0]['count'] as cp 
ORDER BY cp DESC
```

Comment: That's it. thank you!
Final form should be `MATCH (c :Customer)-->(o :Order)-->(p :Product) 
WITH c, o, count(p) as cp ORDER BY cp DESC
WITH c, collect({order: o, count: cp}) as orders
RETURN c, 
       orders[0]['order'] as o`